# symfony2 entity, repository, service confusion

Tags: php, symfony, architecture

I am a little confused about the service, entity and repository and where I should be putting what for the project im working on.  I think im missing something and im worried im going about it in the wrong way.  I dont think doctrine mapping table names is ideal for reports because there are lots of columns and the columns are often results of other groupby on date, month year, etc..

Brief simplified overview of project is a collection of web based reports (as bundles).

In order to create the reports I have to pre-build the data using a sales journal bundle.  The sales journal fetches the data from the transactional database and puts it into tables ready to be run by various other reports i.e. ones that have custom indexes etc. Data aggregation is a better way to explain it. Data source has millions of bookings data going back years so its not efficient to base reports directly on the source so thats where sales journal comes in.

```
SalesJournalBundle      - fetches data from source and puts it into a table ready for other reports
WeeklyConversionReportBundle  - exports sales journal into weekly conversion report table has functions for totals for the week, totals for month, etc
OtherReportBundle             - etc
```

**salesJournal**

class to run the sales journal and export from big table to another table.

```
createQuery($parameters);
runQuery($exportTableName);
```

**WeeklyConversionBundle**

```
// runs the sales journal and saves to the report.  Entity? Or Service or Repoistory?
runSalesJournalQuery();  

// generates conversion figures and saves the to the table? Entity Or Service or Repoistory?
generateConversions();   


getWeekTotals();         // used when displaying the report..
getMonthTotals($month)   // used when displaying the report..
getTotals()              // used when displaying the report..
etc.
```

---

So when I started the project I assumed that all the functions belong in the entity class.. however im not sure they are strictly models as they need DB access and access to other classes?  confused where to put the classes/methods.  Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you talk about *running the sales journal and exporting it from a big table to another table*, I think you mean having different `Services` that do minor things and together accomplish this big task.

Let's say you would need a structure like this:

- `ExportSalesJournalService` - This would need a dependency on a `Repository` class that has access to the database. It could be a `SalesJournalRepository` with some custom methods to run custom queries.
- `ImportSalesJournalService` - This would need the same dependency the other one as well.
- `RunSalesJournalService` - Whatever you mean by `running the sales journal`. If it needs the database, solve this with a dependency on a `Repository`. If not, just a pure old fashion PHP class that does some task.

Remeber to try and decouple things the most you can, so you can have independent objects. This is good for maintainability, testability and other things as well.

One other thing to consider is you really don't need to follow the default Symfony Standard Application structure, like I mention in [this post](http://danielribeiro.org/yes-you-can-have-low-coupling-in-a-symfony-standard-edition-application/). This is going to provide you a more low coupling architecture.

`Entities` are, also, pure and plain PHP classes that represent something. They are supposed to be, in most common cases, dumb objects. Never, NEVER, put business specific code or database access into them.

For the *conversion generation*, a custom `Service` is probably the way to go as well. Something named `ConversionGenerationService` or anything close to that.

Remeber to provide the **intent** of the object in its class name. This is really important.

Concerning the reports, I would probably create a `Service` to generate them, based on specific `Repositories`. Remember to resolve the dependencies explicity, through the constructor or setters.

Comment: Thanks for this reply.  I think the keyword running helped.  The running of a sales journal query needs to be a service.  When you extend repository does that mean you have to use doctrine sql?

Comment: A repository is a class provided by doctrine to manage the queries. You can extend it just by adding custom methods to it.

Comment: How do I add the dependency onto the service so that I can run queries?

Comment: You just pass the dependency, either via the service constructor or a setter method.

Comment: How do I do it via the service constructor?

Comment: the example is for mailer?  Looked at it over and over and cant seem to figure out how I do it for a connection?

Answer (score 2):

1. Assuming you are using Doctrine here.
2. Entities should never have queries in them.  They hold data and perhaps some business logic.  So cross them off your list.
3. In general, repositories are the place to put queries.  So start there with runSalesJournalQuery
4. generateConversions probably belongs in a service.  I'm guessing it has to do a bunch of processing before persisting it's results.
5. The get stuff could go in either a repository or service.  If it is mainly a query then start with it in the repository.  If it is mostly processing the results of a query then a service might be better.

Also keep in mind that you can really only have one repository.  Distributing things across multiple services might make your code more manageable.

Comment: Entities should really not hold business logic. They are suppose to be dumb objects to store data and represent something. Business logic should be place inside a [domain model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) or a [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html).

Comment: This could easily degenerate into one of those religious wars thingees.  IMHO entities can and often do hold business logic.  But it is not really relevant to the question.  We both seem to agree that database queries should not go in entities.

Comment: i am using doctrine but for some of the queries im using raw sql simply because the queries are to large.  Is it good practice to put non doctrine queries in the repository?

Comment: It really depends.  But if you are dealing with thousands of records (or more) then you will run into memory limits (with doctrine) very quickly.  You should probably just inject the database connection object into a service and get your stuff running without doctrine.  Especially if you only have one table to deal with.

Comment: how do I inject the connection?

Comment: Just going to give you a hint: doctrine.dbal.default_connection.  Your big picture questions are fine but for these sorts of implementation details you really need to start using the manual.  There is a whole chapter on the service container.

Comment: thanks for the feedback it is much appreciated.  I have read the section for service container and im still confused with it.  I will get it eventually.

Comment: Consider accepting @drgomesp's answer.  I think your original question has been answered.  Open a new one if you are stuck on a specific implementation detail.